# how to code regression for one sided and two sided t test

Tags: regression, t-test

It is my understanding that t tests and a form a linear regression where the categorical predictor is coded with numbers.

For instance,
if I want to see the effect of smoking on maximum running speed
my IV is categorical : Smoker (Yes/No)
my DV is numerical: speed (mph)

I could do it a t test or, from what I've seen, I can do a regression and recode the smoker variable this way for instance: No = 0 and Yes = 1

However I am having trouble finding out if the t value and p value I get correspond to a one-sided t test or a two-sided t test. And whichever it is, how do I code it to get the other?

My intuition is that 0 and 1 is for one-sided and -1 and 1 would be for two-sided but I'm unsure.

I will be very grateful for any help I can get.
I have searched other posts on this website and I haven't found anybody else asking about this specific question, but if there is and I missed it, I apologize for this post and please refer me to the other post.

Comment: The p value and sidedness of the test will depend on what options you have (or haven't) supplied to the software. The typical assumption for t-test and linear regression is that the test is two sided.

Comment: you don't have to change anything in the code to derive the one-sided p-value from the two-sided p-value in this case. The one-sided p-value will be half of the two-sided p-value if the estimate is in the right direction and 1-{half the p-value} if it is in the wrong direction. For example, if the two-sided p-value is 0.03, the one-sided p-value will be either 0.015 or 0.985 and just think about whether or not your data tells you there is some evidence the null hypothesis is false to decide which one it is.